# Multiple variables in one string

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I currently have this piece of code:

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.sample.com   /phpFile.php?firstname=%@",txtfirstName.text];

NSString *strURL2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.sample.com/phpFile.php?lastname=%@",txtlastName.text];
```

But the problem is that this creates two different rows and I want the firstname, last name, and everything else on one row.

So would it be possible to do something like:

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.sample.com   /phpfile.php?firstname=%@",txtfirstName.text,txtlastName.text,txtheight.text,txtweight.text];
```

or do I need to do something more complicated?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.sample.com/phpfile.php?firstname=%@&txtlastName=%@&txtheight=%@&txtweight=%@",txtfirstName.text,txtlastName.text,txtheight.text,txtweight.text];
```

use it and like this

Comment: Bah. Looks like I don´t  have enough reputation to vote it up... :(

Comment: I know it was months ago now. But I still haven't forgotten your help. Now that I have enough reputation... I'm voting you up!

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *strURL = [@"http://www.sample.com/phpfile.php" appendStringWithFormat:@"?firstname=%@&txtlastName=%@&txtheight=%@&txtweight=%@",txtfirstName.text,txtlastName.text,txtheight.text,txtweight.text];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
NSString *subStringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"firstname=%@&txtlastName=%@&txtheight=%@&txtweight=%@",txtfirstName.text,txtlastName.text,txtheight.text,txtweight.text];

NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.sample.com/phpfile.php?%@",subStringURL];
```

Refer to this link if you need more help: [stringWithFormat: method of NSString Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-stringWithFormat_)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Also let me know if you need more help and vote up and accept it if you find it useful.